# How to add Lua Regex to this part?

Tags: lua

I have like a ID: MeshID == "rbxassetid://2542637991" then ....
How I could do in lua that I can use "MeshID == "rbxassetid://XY" then" , so no need to add the exact number?

```
if Stuff:IsA("MeshPart") then
            if MeshID == "rbxassetid://NUMBER" then
                local Distance = game.Players.LocalPlayer:DistanceFromCharacter(Stuff.Position)
                if Distance < least and Distance < 250 then
                    least = Distance
                    Object = Stuff
                end
```

To add at NUMBER the number found in the code, means

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match` function to find the value you need:

```
if Stuff:IsA("MeshPart") then
  local num = tonumber(MeshID:match("rbxassetid://(%d+)"))
  if num then -- this will replace `MeshID == "rbxassetid://NUMBER"` check
```